# The code result error if regex from database, but fine at local const

Tags: javascript, node.js

I thought this code would work, but it didn't.
Node.Js

```
const reply = "Isi seharga Rp 10.000, terima kasih.";
const localRegex = /I.*Rp (?<harga>.*)/;
const sql = 'SELECT regex FROM balasan WHERE nama="satu"';
db.query(sql, function (err, results) {
  //if (err) throw err;
  const regex = results[0].regex;
  console.log(localRegex == regex ? true : false); //return true
  console.log(regex);
  const found = reply.match(regex);
  console.log(found.groups);
});
```

Result: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'groups').

What am I missing?

If I use localRegex, the result is correct.

Comment: What is `reply`? The variable is never set in your code

Comment: Nothing is found using `match`

Comment: found is undefined in your last console.log because in the line above the match did not return any matches

Comment: I think this comparison converts regex to string is not the same `localRegex == regex`

Comment: If `localRegex === regex //return false`. I tried `const regex = results[0].regex.toString();` still the same.

Comment: `/.../` is a regex _literal_, it is not a string. You cannot store a regex literal in a database, but you can store a string holding a regex. This string must not contain the slashes, unless you want to match slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by remove the slash from database. `I.*Rp (?<harga>.*)`.
Even the `console.log(localRegex == regex ? true : false);`  return false.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing means that the **reply.match(regex)** operation is returning **null**. That means there were no matches found in reply base on your provided regular expression pattern.  I don't see where you've also declared the **reply** variable.

So here are few suggestions.

1. Check if **reply** exist, if it doesn't you'll have to create the variable **reply** and make sure it's a valid string you want to apply the regular expression on.
2. Check your regular expression in your database to see if it's the correct expression you want to use.
3. Handle cases where there are no matches found to prevent the TypeError. Check the below code as a guide.

```js
const localRegex = /I.*Rp (?<harga>.*)/;
const sql = 'SELECT regex FROM balasan WHERE nama="satu"';

db.query(sql, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return; // Handle the database query error
  }

  const regex = results[0].regex;
  console.log(localRegex == regex ? true : false); // Return true if regex patterns match

  // Ensure that reply is a valid string you want to match against. if you haven't created it outside the scope of this query, you may need to create it like below
  const reply = "I found Rp 100 in a text";

  const found = reply.match(regex);
  // handle cases where there's no matches found to get rid of the TypeError
  if (found !== null) {
    console.log(found.groups); // Access groups if a match was found
  } else {
    console.log("No match found."); // Handle the case where no match was found
  }
});
```

I hope this is helpful. Please give me a tick or accept as answer if it helps solve your problem

Comment: `const reply = "Isi seharga Rp 10.000, terima kasih.";` console.log(localRegex == regex ? true : false); <- Return true.  If i change `const found = reply.match(regex);` to `const found = reply.match(localRegex)` return [Object: null prototype] { harga: '10.000, terima kasih.' }

Comment: Result with `const found = reply.match(localRegex);`
`PS D:\gmpro> node .\parsing.js
Connected to Database
true
/I.*Rp (?<harga>.*)/
[Object: null prototype] { harga: '10.000, terima kasih.' }`

Comment: You're getting the above issue because it appears the regex in your db doesn't match the localRegex. so check the value return from   

const regex = results[0].regex;

1. print bother the regex and localRegex. check if they're the same. and also if possible check the type using typeof. 

2. if they're both same, please make sure you trim() all whitespaces from the regex return from the db. 

3. if the regex in the db contains any special characters, make sure it's properly escaped.